# Multiplayer fix for missing chunks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Minecraft - Massive Hole In The Ground](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14695/minecraft-massive-hole-in-the-ground)

My server for minecraft has been haveing problems, a big gaping whole the size of one chunk will open up and only one player can see it. this leads to people being able to see where things like diamond are, something i want them to earn. is there a patch or a fix for this?

Comment: Even once the bug is fixed, it will still be possible for modified or custom clients to see diamonds; the server always sends the *entire* chunk to the client, including all buried items.

Answer (score 5):

This is a [known issue](http://notch.tumblr.com/post/2744150759/minecraft-beta-1-2-01-less-bugs-more-framerates) in the current release of minecraft.  If he disconnects and reconnects, the chunk should be visible.

Comment: I can confirm Dave McClelland's workaround. Disconnecting/reconnecting will cause the missing chunk to download in most cases.