# How can I get rid of this black hole in my minecraft world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have interesting bug that I have experienced before but has gone away on its own. This one is not going away though.

I have a giant stripe or chunks missing from my desert biome, I would say probably 7 chunks long.

I'm guessing the chunks are corrupted or something, what was hoping to figure is whether it can repaired or reverted.

Here is a picture of the problem.

[image: Missing chunk of land]

Comment: The water is not even flowing into the hole. What happens when you enter the space?

Comment: I fall to the bottom like quicksand.

Comment: Can you place blocks there?

Comment: Nope, its like it does not exist

Comment: what texture pack is that?

Comment: Sphax purebdcraft 128x

Comment: unloaded chunks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### Reload your chunks

1. Press <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
2. There is no step 2

failing that...

### Reload Minecraft

1. Close Minecraft
2. Reopen Minecraft

failing that...

### Use [MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/).

1. Backup your world
2. Close Minecraft
3. Open the world in MCEdit
4. Using the chunk tool, completely delete the missing chunks
5. Save and close MCEdit
6. Reopen Minecraft and it will regenerate the missing chunks

Comment: Wow you are huge help. Thanks for all the different way to resolve the is problem.

Comment: @Solignis Which one worked?

Comment: Refreshing the chunks and reloading MC, did not have to use MCedit