# what to do about chunks not loading?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Sometimes not loaded chunks create holes in the world. Why is it that some chunks don't load while everything around them gets loaded? Yesterday i traversed such a hole flying, it still didn't load. Is there anything that can be done to avoid such things? It destroys immersion, apart from that chunk being unusable while not loaded.

Comment: log out and back in, that's all you can do as far as I know.

Comment: This is a known bug, filed as [MC-129](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-129). Another thing you do to fix that for good is follow that link, register on Mojang's bug tracker and vote for the issue. The bug is known for a long time, but is not fixed yet - maybe we need more hype.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are three ways to fix a chunk error:

1. Log off and log on again
2. Press F3 + A
3. Reset your Render distance in display options

Sources are [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunks#Chunk_error_Work-arounds) and [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122674/how-can-i-get-rid-of-this-black-hole-in-my-minecraft-world)

**Edit:** As additional information, option 2 and 3 forcibly reload all chunks.

Answer (score 2):

Three ways to help chunks to load

1. Try resetting your world. The chunks may not cooperate with how fast/slow your world is loading.
2. Check your render distance. Make sure your world is not too many/less chunks.
3. Check your WiFi. Another reason your world may not be loading fully is because of WiFi. If you have 2 or less bars, (or none) your world will not load. Try resetting your WiFi if it is running slow.

Answer (score -2):

Use MCEdit if chunks do not load. Make sure you try logging off and back on to make sure beforehand.