# Why are there huge gaps in my world?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

After a long night of gaming with my boyfriend, finally making a nether portal and exploring for a bit, we logged off for the night. However, when I log on this morning to work on stuff, our whole house, along with the ground surrounding it, is just gone.

There are huge holes in the floor, along with small remains from our house and farm. I assumed it was a chunk error, so I tried resetting them, but it didn't work. I tried logging off and back on again, but it did nothing. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling my game, but it did nothing. I checked my other world, and it was completely fine, so I'm being led to the conclusion that the Nether may have destroyed the world; however, from the way the holes are formed it doesn't seem like damage from a mob.

[image]

[image]

Something else that I thought was weird is that some grass that we broke to make room for our farm and egg farm had regenerated. We had two rows of wheat, plus some space for fencing and lighting, and suddenly the grass is back. We also had a panda enclosure with some bamboo, and as you can see in one of the images, the ground under it is gone; but it's still standing tall and proud.

There is also a huge hole behind this area, and I'm really stuck on what the cause could be, because if it was mob damage, I assume it would be a lot less severe and more prominent. If it was missing chunks, it would've been a lot simpler to fix.

[image]

[image]

We've spent so much time on this world, and it would suck so bad to find out there's nothing we can do. I am running Minecraft version 1.17 on Windows 10.

I went back to check on the world. The MB's keep going up, yet there's no change to the world. I found some corrupt files after looking into my world files on my drive. Any ideas on how to recover them?

Comment: Oh... that's... um, different. Welcome to the Arcade! Is this world hosted on some sort of cloud storage (such as Realms or OneDrive) where you could recover from a backup?

Comment: Unfortunately not. This is just a simple world I made for me and my boyfriend to play on. Of course I would’ve made a copy or two of the world if I knew this would happen but obviously this is super unexpected. What do you mean by OneDrive however?

Comment: You can [choose specific folders](https://www.wikihow.com/Back-Up-Files-to-OneDrive#:~:text=%20Backing%20Up%20Using%20the%20OneDrive%20Program%20on,Once%20files%20have%20been%20added%20to...%20More%20) to back up to OneDrive ([a cloud storage service by Microsoft with a free pricing tier](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/onedrive/compare-onedrive-plans?activetab=tab:primaryr1)). It gives you a backup of your local files (though, not as efficient as Realms). Doesn't really solve your issue here, but could help recovery if it happens again. :)

Comment: I see. I will keep that solution in mind. I'm having a roam around on other forums as other people seem to have the same issue. Will keep you posted! :)

Comment: I hope you find an answer. Best of luck, and again, welcome to the Arcade!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get rid of this black hole in my minecraft world?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122674/how-can-i-get-rid-of-this-black-hole-in-my-minecraft-world)

Comment: Sadly no. I've done everything else aside from the MCEdit thing and that only currently supports Java. This world is on Windows 10.

Comment: Looks like a chunk loading error and unfortunately can like not be fixed :(

Comment: @Joachim that's for Java Edition, this can't be a duplicate because it's a different game

Comment: Is the bedrock layer still there? If the chunk was corrupted it would be newly regenerated, so the only thing I can think is that the blocks were somehow replaced with air blocks. But maybe I'm missing something, that's one of the reasons I started the bounty :)

Answer (score 5):

I found this on [Mojang bug tracker](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-98789) that's still unresolved, and reported also for versions 1.17.0, 1.17.2 Hotfix:

> This report covers any of the following occuring without a game crash:
>
> - Chunks (portions of the world) being **wholly or partially** (i.e. below a certain Y-level) **deleted and turned to void/air**
> - Chunks being **reset to a state of initial generation** (This may result in the chunk not matching surrounding chunks that were generated in an earlier version.)
> - Chunks reverting to an earlier saved state (usually the state the chunk was in before the last time that area of the world was visited)

Which seems your same problem. If you need a fix, there's none at the moment...

From a mod's comment:

> Unfortunately, there is no way to make the chunks that have been voided come back. **The data for those chunks is simply gone**. The only thing you can do for future protection is make manual backups of your worlds regularly and restore one if new chunks get voided.

And regarding the technical reason for this, another mod wrote:

> It looks like the data loss doesn’t always affect the entire chunk. In some cases surface (topmost) chunk sections are spared. I think this suggests the issue is related to loading optimization.

It's not clear why it happened, but the bug is known and a lot of issues have been opened. I suggest you follow the thread to receive updates as soon as they occur.

###### UPDATE:

According to the same Mojang bug tracker page, this glitch was fixed in 1.18.0 version update.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to the 1.17 update for Minecraft. Because they increased the maximum depth, some things can glitch out a lot. I'm afraid you can't change this glitch.

Comment: Can you provide a source or further explanation for this? This seems to be a very strange bug due to maximum depth changes.

Comment: +1. I knew about the maximum depth changes but this seems a bit drastic. I appreciate I can't fix the glitch but surely, because it's a glitch, it'll sort itself out? Unless I'm wrong.

Comment: @JessicaWinter unfortunately glitches like this (*if, this is a glitch*) won't be resolved as the data is lost. There's really no way (*to my knowledge*, unless it's a Realms server) to recover world data lost on a scale such as this. Sorry it happened to you. Best of luck!

Comment: @Gnemlock When minecraft comes across something it doesn't like (unknown items, malformed chunk, etc.) it just straight-up removes it to prevent a crash or other weird glitches so it would make sense that in the update some of the data got malformed when converting it. I think this is a probable explanation

Comment: @Gnemlock that was an answer to your question but not an answer to the question being asked.

Comment: @Gnemlock you said it was strange so I explained why that wouldn't be so?

Comment: The max depth changes won't be released until the second part of the 1.17 update, much later this year. I'm shocked nobody else said anything... how could some unreleased feature cause that bug?

Comment: Apparently, this is a known bug since 1.16.1.