# Why are there deleted chunks of bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-education-edition

I pressed the save and quit button in my world and then logged back in later. There's now two weird chunk holes in the bedrock... any ideas to why? Note: the holes in the bedrock aren't ghosted, they're actually just missing. [image: ???]

Comment: There might be better duplicates (I'm not sure how much the edition matters for this specific problem), but I'm sure a similar question has been asked.

Comment: Are they actually gone? Or can you step onto them? In other words, have they been deleted or are just invisible?

Comment: There was a similar bug in Bedrock edition but, according to Mojang bug tracker, was fixed in version 1.18

Comment: @MechMK1 They're not ghost blocks, they're actually gone.

Comment: @pinckerman can you post a link to the bug?

Comment: From [Why are there huge gaps in my world?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/387235/why-are-there-huge-gaps-in-my-world): see [here](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-98789)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are there huge gaps in my world?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/387235/why-are-there-huge-gaps-in-my-world)